# AbstractMethodError when calling setClientInfo using DB2 and myBatis

Tags: java, db2, mybatis

Using DB2 and myBatis. Some background: I have a trigger on a table that should fire when a row is deleted and insert the row into a history table, and I want the user that deleted the row (not the connection user) to be reflected in a column of this table.

So far, I've written the trigger so that it uses DB2's `CLIENT_USERID` register to get the user, and also a myBatis interceptor that should set the user whenever a statement is prepared using `setClientInfo` on the Connection.

The interceptor class is annotated as follows:

```
@Intercepts({@Signature(
        type = StatementHandler.class,
        method = "prepare",
        args = {Connection.class})})
```

Interception works, but when I try to call the `setClientInfo` method on the argument of the intercept method (Connection), it turns out that that method is abstract.

Is there a simpler way to do this or will this work and how do I fix this?

Thanks for looking at this post!